# Diagonal stripes that are 1px wide

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to give an element a background with repeating, 1px wide diagonal stripes. It seems that `repeating-linear-gradient` should be able to do this, but when rendered in Safari this:

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg, black, black 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 3px
);
```

[Looks like this](http://jsfiddle.net/SR4gL/1/):

```css
#thing {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, black, black 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 3px);
}
```

```html
<div id="thing"></div>
```

It looks as though the browser's doing a poor job of [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing), resulting in an uneven banding pattern. Any ideas on how I might be able to fix this, or to accomplish what I'm looking to do another way?

Comment: it looks even worse in chrome

Comment: and as worse in Firefox :)

Comment: When you mean 1px wide stripes, is it 1px across diagonally, or 1px when measured across the x/y axis? The moire pattern you see is due to anti-aliasing in browsers.

Comment: @Terry I want lines comprised of 1px blocks. I tried doing some crazy stuff like specifying stops of 1.414px (length of the diagonal), but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: @KyleCronin You're out of luck here - if you are familiar with the [Pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple), it is not possible to get a square block (with side lengths that are integers) with a diagonal width of also an integer, and vice versa... this is because of the basic rule that on a square block of 1*1px wide, the diagonal width is sqrt(2), which is an irrrational number.

Comment: @Terry Right, hence the 1.414px (roughly sqrt(2)) that I tried that didn't work either. Any other options that might not involve repeating-linear-gradient?

Comment: @KyleCronin Just added my answer :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

A little more elabourate explanation of the conundrum here: according to the Pythagoras principle (and its triples), it is impossible to have a square (which is simply two right triangles fit together) whose sides are integers that has a diagonal whose length is an integer number, too.

This is because 1<sup>2</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup> = sqrt(2)<sup>2</sup>. Since the square root of 2 is an irrational number, all derivatives of this (a square of whatever side length that is an integer number) will have a diagonal of irrational length.

This is the closest I can get — specify an integer square, but the stripes will be of non-integer width: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/SR4gL/2/

```
#thing {
    height: 200px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, black 50%, black 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-size: 4px 4px;
}
```

The side lengths of the imaginary square, tiled over your element, will be 4px wide. This means the diagonal length would be sqrt(32), and the stripe will be 1.414...px when measured diagonally across (close to 1, but not quite there), or 2px wide when measured parallel to the x or y axis.

Comment: I still see weird stuff in that gradient, though to its credit it is much more regular. I was, however, able to take your idea and get the gradient that I needed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it possible if you use a rectangle rather than a square?

Comment: @kgrote Square is a must, since OP stated that the stripes should be 45deg.

Comment: Why doesn't the 1.414px thing work? Surely once the browser anti-aliases it the small discrepancy between 1.414px and sqrt(2) won't be noticeable, since it'll just make the pixels a teeny bit more transparent, or add some really transparent pixels adjacent to them (depending which way the discrepancy is)? In fact, why can't the browser anti-alias the sqrt(1/2)px wide line in the first place?

Comment: @CameronMartin Because non-integer pixel values don't exist, and I actually don't really understand your comment. I didn't say that 1.414...px is a problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, I copy and pasted it from the comments of the question because I realised it was addressed to you, but didn't realise it wouldn't have any context any more. Kyle said that he tried using an approximation to sqrt(2) as the width of the gradient, and it didn't work; I was wondering why. But this answers my question. Does the browser just ignore the fractional part rather than antialias it?

Comment: To draw a 1.5px vertical black line, why can't the browser draw a 1px black line alongside a 1px black line with 0.5 alpha? Surely this same idea would be applied to the above problem to make it look reasonable?

Comment: This is just what I need. It's much less abrasive if you use a grey like #dfdfdf or something similar. Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

Many thanks to Terry for his [suggested approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23878685/658) of using a standard `linear-gradient` with percentages and a `background-size`. With a bit of playing around, I have managed to obtain the [exact gradient I was looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/SR4gL/3/):

[image]

```
background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right top,
    transparent 33%,
    black 33%,
    black 66%,
    transparent 66%
);
background-size: 3px 3px;
```

Comment: That looks actually like what I was also looking for, but with the current chrome version (58) this flickers like some sort of old school TV. Happens also in Firefox...

Comment: @FlorianMuller Make the dots bigger. Then, there will be less of that effect. Also apply `image-rendering: pixelated`.