# Remove color transition on gradient with css

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to use Gradient as background for `<div>` to achieve three-colored background.
I'm able to actually fill it with three colors with css:

```
.threecolored{
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(29,219,8,1) 0%,rgba(255,30,30,1) 50%,rgba(23,100,234,1) 100%); 
    }
```

so I'm getting this gradient (by color transition I mean part changing between green/red or blue/red, not time transition)
[image: result of style above]

Is there way to change that gradient to look more like this one
[image: desired state of gradient]
or should I use different CSS (or js?) mechanism?

I'd be able to split that `<div>` into three and color each them separately but it would degrade use-case purpose of this.

Thanks.

EDIT: I believe it's slightly different than [Diagonal stripes in CSS that are 1px wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878398/diagonal-stripes-in-css-that-are-1px-wide) since that one is related completing background by combining of fragments.
Working asnwer is already mentioned in comment.

Comment: `linear-gradient(to right, rgb(29,219,8) 33%, rgb(255,30,30) 33%, rgb(255,30,30) 67%, rgb(23,100,234) 67%)` - the trick is to duplicate the stops on the transition points so it changes colour immediately.

Comment: thanks, it worked for -webkit-linear-gradient and -moz-linear-gradient as well. In case you'll retype it to answer I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: The duplicate link show exactly how to **solve** your issue (hence being a duplicate), as it use duplicate stops to make color not blended, whether that is on a fragment or not doesn't matter.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  Being a more experienced user here than I, and if you think the dupe link does not represent a valid answer for this question, feel free to reopen and post your comment as an answer. I can agree with the fact that the question itself appears being far from a dupe, but its answers is not.