# Make horizontal line spanning to width of container using pseudo css elment

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I want to make a a horizontal line spanning to the width of the container in which it is placed. The lined element should look like this:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Very much like a horizontal rule. I have tried it but 100% width is taken only when I put enough slashes in the content property of pseudo element. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div style='width: 100%;>
   <p class='horizontal-line'></p>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.horizontal-line:before
{
 content: '///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////';
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: purple;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 10px;
}
```

The result is:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////
```

But it does not span to 100% width of outer div. In order to do so I have to put more slashes in content property. I know there is some alternate and better way to achieve this.

P.S: I am not very good at working with pseudo element and might be doing something wrong. Can anyone point out?

Edit: And if I place many slashes in content property then the horizontal line goes to two lines when placed in smaller container. 
[Here is fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln428h6n/)

Comment: I think you should go with background-image and repeat the X to 100%

Comment: No actually I want to color this line dynamically, the color will be chosen by the user and line will be colored with that chosen color so can't use images

Comment: I think the best idea would be to create these lines as much as needed in an svg file, put it inside the horizontal line element and give it `width:100%; overflow:hidden;`

Comment: @AminJafari like this right https://jsfiddle.net/Lq8erreo/6/

Comment: Thanks a lot @AminJafari

Comment: @SanthoshKumar that's right

Comment: You can add your fiddle as answer. I don't want to use gradient because I don't want to code for gradient as the color of this line will be dynamic and selected by user on runtime.

Comment: but I think @priya_singh 's idea is much more elegant and reliable, I'd do that if I were you

Comment: you can set this gradient in js and put the color in a variable and change it whenever you want

Comment: If `js` is allowed, use loop function and add `/` in `p` tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should try linear-gradient. Please find the below code.

```css
.horizontal-line:before
{
 content: '';
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: purple;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 font-size: 10px;
 display:block;
 background: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,purple,purple .25em,transparent 0,transparent .75em );

}
```

```html
<div style='width: 100%;'>
   <p class='horizontal-line'></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Outpus nothing in fiddle.

Comment: why have you given it to the `:before` pseudo element? it works on `.horizontal-line` too => https://jsfiddle.net/Ln428h6n/4/

Comment: yes. Obvious. But i thought he wants for before thats why

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: edited @priya_singh fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ln428h6n/6/. If the user can change the color. Handle it by changing the background-color to the p tag

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with css `background` property like this:

```css
.horizontal-line {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10px;
 background: purple linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) repeat scroll 0 0 / 40px 40px
}
```

```html
<div style='width: 100%;'>
   <p class='horizontal-line'></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options here

1. Use **very long `content`** and set it's parent overflow to hidden .
2. Use css [**`linear-gradient`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) to draw your stripes. Problem here is, the gradient may look poor (looks like aliasing issue). But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23878685/619616) is a great explanation and suggestion how to overcome this.
3. Draw your pattern as **image and use background repeat**, you can draw your pattern online (i.e. http://www.patternify.com/ ) and use just base64 version of image

Here is are examples of all three options:

```css
p { width: 80%; margin: 0px auto; margin-top: 30px; padding: 0; }
.container { width: 80%; border: 2px solid #888; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px 0; }
.horizontal-line { width: 100%; height: 10px; }

.horizontal-line-v1 { overflow: hidden; }
.horizontal-line-v1:before
{
 content: '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////';
 color: purple;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.horizontal-line-v2 { 
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, purple 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, purple 50%, purple 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-size: 4px 4px;
}

.horizontal-line-v3 {
  background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAKElEQVQYV2NkQAMNDA3/GZHFQAINDA2McEGYAEgRWBBZACyILgASBACrXQ4FrzarHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
}
```

```html
<p>Stripes using :before and content</p>
<div class="container">
   <div class='horizontal-line horizontal-line-v1'></div>
</div>

<p>Stripes using css linear-gradient</p>
<div class="container">
   <div class='horizontal-line horizontal-line-v2'></div>
</div>

<p>Stripes using base64 image</p>
<div class="container">
   <div class='horizontal-line horizontal-line-v3'></div>
</div>
```

[Here is jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buksy/bdyydnkb/)

Answer (score 0):

If it actually needs to be a `///`-line, then you can trick it a bit using an image. ;)

```css
.my-line
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 11px;
    background: url("//i.imgur.com/OMxDsnu.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<p>Before Line</p>
<div class="my-line"></div>
<p>After Line</p>
```