# Crosshatch effect with repeating-linear-gradient results in uneven pattern

Tags: css

I am attempting to create a diagonal crosshatching pattern as a background in CSS. I started with the examples for striped backgrounds in [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/).

```css
.crosshatch {
 width: 500px;
 height: 200px;
  color: white;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 1px,
 transparent 1px,
 transparent 5px
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="crosshatch"></div>
```

However, I am seeing (only in Chrome and Opera) that after eight repetitions at 1px, the line becomes 2px wide for the next six iterations, before going back to the correct 1px width.

[image: Example of output]

I don't get this problem in Edge and Firefox.

Is there a work around for Chrome and Opera?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't seem to find a perfect solution. This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/SR4gL/2/) from this [Stack Overflow Question - "Diagonal stripes in CSS that are 1px wide"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878398/diagonal-stripes-in-css-that-are-1px-wide/23878685#23878685)  seems to be in agreement with the complications mentioned near the bottom of this [CSS-Tricks tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/why-do-we-have-repeating-linear-gradient-anyway/)

```
.crosshatch {
   width: 500px;
   height: 200px;
   color: white;
   background-image: linear-gradient(
      45deg, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 25%, 
      transparent 25%, 
      transparent 50%, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 50%, 
      rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 75%, 
      transparent 75%, 
      transparent
      );
   background-size: 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: lol - I should have used a little lateral thinking on that one and actually found that other question. I'll mark this as duplicate. Thanks for pointing that out and coming up with a working solution.